# Number of maxima of the sum of two functions

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, maxima-minima

Let two functions $f(x), g(x)$ be defined on an interval $E\subseteq\mathbb R$. On that interval, $f$ has $p$ isolated local maxima, and $g$ has $q$ isolated local maxima. By "isolated", I mean that if $x$ is an isolated maximum of $f$, then $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $f(y)<f(x)$(strict inequality) whenever $|y-x|\leq \epsilon.$ Assume that all maxima of $f,g$ are isolated, so we are excluding the case where $f$ is a constant function on a subset of $E$.

Assume also that all the maxima of $f+g$ are isolated. $f+g$ has $r$ maxima. Given that $p,q\geq 1$, **is it always true that $r\leq p+q$?** Assume $f,g$ to be continuous or smooth or anything if we need it. Or is it true in some special cases(e.g. non-negative $f,g$)?

It is not true for $p=q=0$. Just take $f(x)=-x$ and $g(x)=x^3$ as a counterexample. However, I struggle to produce any counterexample for nontrivial values of $p,q$ (such as $2,3$).

Comment: An idea. Smoothly modify your counterexample for  $(p,q) = (0,0)$ to alter $f$ and $g$ when $x > 3$ so that each has some local maxima.You can do that and keep infinite differentiability.

Comment: @EthanBolker I thought of using $f(x) = -Kx^5+Hx^3$ instead of $f(x) = x^3$, so that I have an inflection point in $0$ and a maximum somwhere for positive $x$. Now we would need $g(x)$ such that $g(x) \sim x$ in $0$ and with, also a maximum for positive $x$, this would generate an "extra" maximum for negative $x$, thus creating a counterexample for the case $p=q=1$.